# jqGrid hiding Plus icon

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid with subGrid. But at some row i do not want to show the Plus icon. Because i do not want to allow user to view the subgrid on that perticular row. So can any body help me how to hide the plus icon over there. I tried with the below code but no luck.

```
afterInsertRow : function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
$("tr[id="+rowid+"]>td.ui-sgcollapsed>a")
                           .click(function(){return false;})
}
```

By doing above i can disable the Plus icon that is on click of plus icon subgrid will not open. But, my requirement is to not to show the Plus icon at all. 
when i am doing like below then borders are not coming in IE6 while in mozila borders are coming.

```
$("tr#1.ui-widget-content td:first span").removeAttr("class");
```

Also by wrting above code it is on click of the cell again Plus icon comes up.

Can any body tell me how to hide plus icon. and disable its click event?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
      $("tr[id=" + rowid + "]>td:first").removeAttr("class");
      $("tr[id=" + rowid + "]>td:first").html("&nbsp;");
}
```

Comment: how about removing the td and th completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the onGridComplete event.  When the grid is completed loading you will need to find the rows that you want to remove the plus icon from.  Finally, remove the class that is used to determine the style of the plus icon

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach. Do you have any example code to get him started?

Answer (score 0):

This works even if you have activate multiselect. (:first referres to checkbox column)

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
   $("tr[id=" + rowid + "]>td[aria-describedby$=_subgrid]").removeAttr("class");
   $("tr[id=" + rowid + "]>td[aria-describedby$=_subgrid]").html("&nbsp;");
}
```